# Append a new column, to each row, with text equivalent of the first column value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

Note: I didn't create this table, I am an end-user trying to make my life easier.

What I need to do is to copy this table to excel, but the first and second column are in input box style.

I want to create a new column at the end of the row that has the same exact value of the first column but in text, so I can copy and sort in excel.

I tried this in Greasemonkey but didn't work:

```
$("tr").append("<td>rows[1].innerHTML</td>")
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Document Name</td>
            <td>File Name</td>
            <td>Last Updated</td>
            <td>Email Target</td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="documentId" value="5723">
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="30" name="name_5723" value="document1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="30" name="fileName_5723" value="document1.pdf">
            </td>
            <td>05/26/2015 10:40 AM</td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:document+5723@mega.com">document+5723@mega.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="documentId" value="5722">
    </tbody>
```

The desired output would look something like this:
[image: desired output]

Comment: Sorry. I don't really know the correct syntax. I thought rows would be correct. Which syntax should I use

Comment: you mean you want to add to each row a cell (on the right) holding the exact value of the first one `document blah blah`?

Comment: Also `input` **cannot** be a child element of Table... It's wrong... :(

Comment: Here is what I was talking about http://imgur.com/BP1y0st

Comment: All of these tables are under the <form method="post">, so I think that's why the input box is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes about the question code:

1. You need a better selector. `$("tr")` is way too broad and will alter every table on the page!
2. You need to account for the header row.
3. If your page is AJAX-driven, you must use AJAX aware techniques or the script will not see the table you care about.

That said, here is **a complete Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script** that will append a text column to the HTML provided in the question:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Append text column
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements (
    "form > table:contains('Document Name') tr", appendTextColumn
);

function appendTextColumn (jNode) {
    var firstCol    = jNode.find ("td:eq(0)");
    var cellContent = firstCol.find ("input").val ()  ||  firstCol.text ();

    jNode.append ('<td>' + cellContent + '</td>');
}
```

---

---

Equivalent **code that only works on *static* pages**:

```js
var targTable   = $("form > table:contains('Document Name')");
if (targTable.length !== 1)
    alert ('GM script error:  Expected 1 document table but found ' + targTable.length + '!');

targTable.find ("tr").append (function (idx){
    var firstCol    = $("td:eq(0)", this);
    if (idx === 0)
        return '<td>' + firstCol.text () + '</td>'

    return '<td>' + firstCol.find ("input").val () + '</td>'
} );
```

```js
var targTable   = $("form > table:contains('Document Name')");
if (targTable.length !== 1)
    alert ('GM script error:  Expected 1 document table but found ' + targTable.length + '!');

targTable.find ("tr").append (function (idx){
    var firstCol    = $("td:eq(0)", this);
    if (idx === 0)
        return '<td>' + firstCol.text () + '</td>'

    return '<td>' + firstCol.find ("input").val () + '</td>'
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Document Name</td>
            <td>File Name</td>
            <td>Last Updated</td>
            <td>Email Target</td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="documentId" value="5723">
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="30" name="name_5723" value="document1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="30" name="fileName_5723" value="document1.pdf">
            </td>
            <td>05/26/2015 10:40 AM</td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:document+5723@mega.com">document+5723@mega.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="documentId" value="5722">
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zavijo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
$("tr").append(function(){
  return $("td:eq(0)", this).clone();
});
```

P.S: note that by simply using `$("tr")` as selector might target unwanted TR elements on the page, make sure to add an ID to your table like:

```
<table id="myTable">
```

and use it in jQuery: `$("#myTable tr")`

Comment: I didn't create the table. How can I add the table id into existing html using javascript?